# ASP.NET WebAPI methods working only local but not on WebServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I created a WebAPI and all routes and methods work perfectly locally:
[WebAPI Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDrXE.png)

The problem is when I put it on my web server(The local and web tests are on the same server, so the connection string to the database is correct.).

The standard website and standard methods work normally, but the ones I created don't work(500 Internal Server Error):

[WebAPI Server Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzfrd.png)

[WebAPI Server Web Default Methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCUPn.png)

[WebApi Server Web Default WebSIte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhtYC.png)

How can it work perfectly local and not web? since nothing has changed in the code?

The error is as if the url did not exist.

These are the code for the web api method and the RouteConfig file

```csh
        [Route("WebApi/Users/GetAll")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
        {
            return _userRep.All;
        }
```

```csh
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

**UPDATE:** Looking in the windows application event logs, I noticed several errors related to localdb. I don't know why it didn't work with LocalDB. As my server is also a domain controller, I had problems getting the SQL server installed but I managed with this tutorial: [http://lexisnexis.custhelp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1089877/~/installing-sql-on -a-domain-controller](http://lexisnexis.custhelp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1089877/%7E/installing-sql-on-a-domain-controller)

After that I pointed to the SQLServe instance instead of LocalDB and it worked.

Comment: `_userRep.All` retrieves data from the database? Are you using proper connection string while deploying to the web server?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, the data is returned from the database.
Yes. The connection string is correct, as I said it works normally local (The local test and the Web are on the same server).
It is with error 500, as if the URL did not exist.

Comment: @BrunoSouza please elaborate what errors your web server is returning - post error messages.

Comment: Are using the same connection string for local and the web server? @BrunoSouza

Comment: @AlexBuyny Error 500. The error is as if the url did not exist

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes. The server is the same for both tests.

Comment: "url does not exist" - I'd expect 404 then

Comment: @AlexBuyny I agree. I looked at the logs but there are no details, just: "2020-06-26 01:40:27 151.80.130.233 GET /NinjaScalperWebService/WebApi/Users/GetAll - 8080 - 172.68.24.145 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/81.0.4044.138+Safari/537.36+OPR/68.0.3618.173 - 500 0 0 37747"

Comment: You should use some logging framework, use try catch in GetAll method and log the exception/error. And analyze the log file to see what's issue.

Comment: If you're getting HTTP code 500 back, [that means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) there was an error in the code in your method. If the route wasn't found, you would get a 404.  So, as @ChetanRanpariya mentions, you could put some more meaningful information in your logging method or log something at the beginning and end of the method.  One other thing to check is to see what's in your configuration in your `Application_Start` directory or maybe `global.asax` or other config files. Maybe you are targeting a port that only works locally.

Comment: I discovered several errors in the event viewer for LocalDB. I believe the problem is in it. The problem is that I cannot install SQLServer because it is a domain controller.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide more information about your controller

place this on the controller if not present
`[Route("api/[controller]")]`

Comment: The route is already present: [Route("WebApi/Users/GetAll")]